# Не получается присвоить значение переменной экземпляра

Tags: java, android, переменные, android-intent, int

Есть активность(дочерняя):

```
public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_is_true"; // ключ для получения дополнения с правильным ответом
    private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown"; // ключь для передачи данных о том, видел ли пользовательно ответ
    private static final String EXTRA_MASS_CHEAT =
            "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.mass.cheat"; // ключ для массива случаев, когда пользователь нажал на кнопку просмотра ответа

    private static final String GHEAT_INDEX = "cheat";
    private static final String GHEAT_INDEX_TEXT = "text";

    private boolean isAnswerShown = false; //переменная, в которой сахраняются данные о том, нажимал ли пользователь на просмотр правильного ответа
    private static final String KEY_SHOWN = "shown";

    private boolean mAnswerIsTrue; // правильный ответ


    private TextView mAnswerTextView;
    private Button mShowAnswerButton;

    private boolean [] arrayCheat = new boolean[6];
    public int arrayIndex = new QuizActivity().mCurrentIndex;

    // private boolean mIsCheater;

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue, boolean [] arrayCheat, int arrayIndex) { // с помощью этого метода главная активность передаёт данные в дочернию
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
        new CheatActivity().arrayCheat = arrayCheat;
        new CheatActivity().arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
        return intent;
    }

    public static boolean wasAnswerShown(Intent result) {
        return result.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false); // getBooleanExtra - метод для чтения значения из дополнения
    }

    public static boolean [] massCheat(Intent array){
        return array.getBooleanArrayExtra(EXTRA_MASS_CHEAT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            QuizActivity.mIsCheater = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(GHEAT_INDEX, false);
            arrayCheat = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray(GHEAT_INDEX_TEXT); 
            isAnswerShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOWN, false);
          //  new QuizActivity().cheatArray = arrayCheat;
            mAnswerIsTrue = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(GHEAT_INDEX_TEXT, false);
        }

        mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false); // получение данных из intent

        mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);

        if (isAnswerShown){
            setAnswerShownResult(isAnswerShown, arrayCheat);
        }

        mShowAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
        mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
                } else {
                    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
                }

                arrayCheat[arrayIndex] = true;
                isAnswerShown = true;
                setAnswerShownResult(isAnswerShown, arrayCheat);
                QuizActivity.mIsCheater = true;
                new QuizActivity().cheatArray[arrayIndex] = true;

            }
        });
        // mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(GHEAT_INDEX, QuizActivity.mIsCheater);
        outState.putBooleanArray(GHEAT_INDEX_TEXT, arrayCheat);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
       // outState.putBoolean(GHEAT_INDEX_TEXT, mAnswerIsTrue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown, boolean [] mass) { // возвращает в главную активность информацию о том, подсматривал ли пользователь ответ
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown); // передайт true, если пользовательно подсматривал ответ (вторая переменная)
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_MASS_CHEAT, mass);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data); // возвращает данные в главную активность
    }

}
```

В неё отправляются некоторые данные из главной активности, после чего переменная arrayIndex становится равна 2 (или любому другому числу, которое было передано из главной активности)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, после запуска этой (дочерней) активности, переменная  arrayIndex становится равна нулю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему это происходит и что с этим делать

Comment: В моем ответе, если Вы его уже просмотрели, была ошибка!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы присваиваете значение не тому экземпляру активности, который выводится на экран.

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue, boolean [] arrayCheat, int arrayIndex) { // с помощью этого метода главная активность передаёт данные в дочернию
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    new CheatActivity().arrayCheat = arrayCheat;
    new CheatActivity().arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
    return intent;
}
```

Класс Intent (от слова Intention, намерение) позволяет Вам запустить другую активность. Явное создание активности через `new CheatActivity()` никак тут не участвует. По сути, Вы как бы "просите" Android открыть активность, указанную в Intent. Если Android соизволит ее открыть - то сам создаст экземпляр класса.

Для передачи массива (и его размера) в другую активность нужно использовать putExtra.

```
intent.putExtra("Ваш ключ для массива", arrayCheat);
intent.putExtra("Ваш ключ для размера массива", arrayIndex);
```

Строки

```
new CheatActivity().arrayCheat = arrayCheat;
new CheatActivity().arrayIndex = arrayIndex;
```

Лишние.

Когда активити будет запущена, Вы сможете получить свой массив следующим кодом:

```
cheatArray = getIntent().extras.getBooleanArray("Ваш ключ для массива");
cheatIndex = getIntent().extras.getInt("Ваш ключ для размера массива");
```

Comment: Премного благодарен)

Comment: Я сделал немного другим путём, но, Вы меня навели на правильную мысль

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых никто никогда не создаёт активити через new. Все активити создаёт система. Вам стоит почитать о том как работает активити.

И исходя из первого замечания тот что вы присваиваете значение активити не даёт ровным счётом ничего. Вам необходимо создавать интент, класть в него необходимые данные и во второй активити извлекать их.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class); 
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId); 
startActivity(intent);

String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: Благодарю Вас!)